# git branch, but changes reflect in master

Tags: linux, git, git-branch

I've created a branch as `git branch my_branch`, then `git checkout my_branch`, work in it, however when I switch back in master `git checkout master` I do see these changes in master as well. I assume this should not be happening.

```
% git checkout my_branch
Switched to branch 'my_branch'

<I make my changes>

% git status
On branch my_branch
Changes not staged for commit:
...

% git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
% git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
...
<Shows the same changed files as in my_branch>
```

What am I possibly doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you commit your changes on your new branch before checking out master?

Comment: What do you get with a `git status` and `git log`?

Comment: @Ross, I updated my question

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen, no I didn't commit the changes. Did I have to?

Comment: The behaviour is absolutely normal: your uncommited changes will remain even if you checkout your branch

Comment: @Mark why do you expect the changes to disappear without committing or stashing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uncommitted changes in either the working directory or the staging area (i.e. the index) do *not* belong to any branch yet. So when you checkout another branch, that does not affect those changes. `git status` still shows them as, well, uncommitted.